# Rails saving arrays to separate rows in the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Could someone take a look at my code and let me know if there is a better way to do this, or even correct where I'm going wrong please? I am trying to create a new row for each venue and variant.

Example:

```
venue_ids => ["1","2"], variant_ids=>["10"]
```

So, I would want to add in a row which has a `venue_id of 1`, with `variant_id of 10`. And a `venue_id of 2`, with `variant_id of 10`

I got this working, and it's now passing in my two arrays. I think I am almost there I'm not sure the `.each` is the right way to do it, but I think that I'm on the right track haha. I have it submitting, however, where would I put my `@back_bar.save`? because this might cause issues as it won't redirect

Thanks in advance.

```
def create
  @back_bar = BackBar.new
  @venues = params[:venue_ids]
  @productid = params[:product_id]
  @variants = params[:variant_ids]

  # For each venue we have in the array, grab the ID.
  @venues.each do |v|
    @back_bar.venue_id = v
    # Then for each variant we associate the variant ID with that venue.
    @variants.each do |pv|
      @back_bar.product_variant_id = pv

      # Add in our product_id
      @back_bar.product_id = @productid
      # Save the venue and variant to the DB.

      if @back_bar.save
        flash[:success] = "#{@back_bar.product.name} has been added to #{@back_bar.venue.name}'s back bar."
        # Redirect to the back bar page
        redirect_to back_bars_path
      else
        flash[:alert] = "A selected variant for #{@back_bar.product.name} is already in #{@back_bar.venue.name}'s back bar."
         # Redirect to the product page
        redirect_to discoveries_product_path(@back_bar.product_id)
      end
    end # Variants end
  end # Venues end
end

private

  def back_bar_params
    params.require(:back_bar).permit(:venue_id,
                                     :product_id,
                                     :product_variant_id)
  end
```

Comment: Huh? you're overwriting the same one record. You're not creating multiple records.

Comment: you really need to learn to write slim controllers. 
you should make a model method where you just throw in the ids. for that case, you can also write a test for it and ensure that its working.
i would also do this with a mass sql statement instead of using AR for that. imagine you have 20x20 ids. so you do 1 statement instead of 400

Comment: @huanson that's what i would like to do, do you know of any tutorials which could help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i said in comments

this is untested code and just showing you how it's possible to do with ease.

```
class BackBar

  def self.add_set(vanue_ids, variant_ids)
    values = vanue_ids.map{|ven|
      variant_ids.map{|var|
        "(#{ven},#{var})"
      }
    }.flatten.join(",")

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO back_bars VALUES #{values}")
  end
end

def create
  # use in controller
  BackBar.add_set(params[:venue_ids], params[:variant_ids])

  # ...
end
```

Comment: oh thanks! @huanson this is much appreciated and a great starting point.
So is it fine to use the SQL insert in there?

Comment: yes of course. that's why we can do it. as i said. imagine you have 50x50 values. you wanna do 2.500 SQL statements or rather just one single mass-insert? also you now can test your model-behavior and write a unit test, calling the method and see that it creates expected count of columns